# Quaternion.Lerp function gives error; Assertion failed on expression: '!CompareApproximately(aScalar, 0.0F)'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a system where the user can use space bar to gradually turn a vehicle to 90 degrees, and the vehicle stays fully turned while space bar is held, but the vehicle gradually returns to 0 degrees rotation when input ceases.

When I put the timer variable that gradually goes up and down into a Lerp function, it just gives me the error: Assertion failed on expression: '!CompareApproximately(aScalar, 0.0F)'

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static float turnTimer = 2f;
    private float turnTimeElapsed;
    private float clampedTimeElapsed;
    private float lerpTimer;

    [SerializeField] private float turnSpeed;

    Quaternion endRot;

    Rigidbody ridgy;

    private void Start()
    {
        ridgy = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        turnTimeElapsed = 0f;

        Quaternion endRot = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 90f, 0f);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && turnTimeElapsed < turnTimer)
        {
            turnTimeElapsed += turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            
        }
        else if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && turnTimeElapsed > 0)
        {
            turnTimeElapsed -= turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        clampedTimeElapsed = Mathf.Clamp(turnTimeElapsed, 0f, turnTimer);

        lerpTimer = clampedTimeElapsed / turnTimer;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Quaternion.identity, endRot, lerpTimer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to be using lerp here, just construct the quat directly.

`90 degrees` --> `90 * PI/180 * 0.5` --> `PI/4` [quats take half angles, hence the 0.5]

Given that the quat is defined as:

```cpp
xyz = sin(angle/2) * Axis
w = cos(angle/2)
```

And you wish to have a rotation around the y axis (0,1,0), so just construct the quaternion directly.

```cpp
transform.rotation = new Quaternion(
 0,
 Mathf.Sin(lerpTimer * Mathf.PI/4.0),
 0,
 Mathf.Cos(lerpTimer * Mathf.PI/4.0)
);
```

Comment: tbh I would usually rather rely on the built-in ways instead of manually dealing with Quaternions ^^

Comment: tbh, if you're converting Euler angles to quaternions, you're doing it wrong imho.

Comment: Not really no .. this direction the conversion is completely reliable and valid and especially if you have no clue how quaternion works you shouldn't be touching its individual components at all ^^

Comment: I mean basically you do the same thing.. just without going through the built-in method for doing it ;) Instead of interpolating the resulting Quaternions you interpolate the underlying Euler angles and then convert that to quaternion again...

Comment: No, I am NOT rotating Euler angles and converting to a quat, I am constructing the quat by an axis-angle. Euler triplet to quat conversions involve constructing 3 quats and then multiplying them:  QX(rotX, axis {1,0,0}) * QY(rotY, axis {0,1,0}) * QZ(rotZ, axis {0,0,1}).  Should the middle angle be +/- 90 degrees, you have a gimbal lock. (Quats only solve gimbal lock if you use a single quat! Your original code sets up a perfect gimbal lock situation).

Comment: I could have generated the quat from an axis (0,1,0) and angle (lerpTimer * pi/2). That would equally work, however you'd incur additional multiplications that don't need to be there.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, as the code you wrote does indeed work as intended, but it really doesn't help me in solving or understanding the error I was experiencing, and I don't understand how your solution works.

Comment: `Your original code sets up a perfect gimbal lock situation` why? I see one rotation over time from identity to 90° on the Y axis .. why should a gimbal lock occur here? And `90 degrees --> 90 * PI/180 * 0.5 --> PI/4` is literally converting OP's 90° angle to quaternion components.. pretty much the same thing `Quaternion.Euler` will do for you .. As someone who has been coding for 25 years you should know that you rather prefer to use a well tested and maintained library instead of reimplantating things from scratch tbh ;)

Comment: If you have an Euler rotation order, lets assume XYZ. If you rotate the middle one (Y) by 90 degrees, then you have collapsed the X axis (YZ) onto the Z axis (XY). It is the literal definition of gimbal lock. 

It isn't just converting the 90 degree angle to quaternion components. That's what an axis angle to quat conversion will do (As I have just explained above). Euler angle triplets to quaternion involve 3x axis angle conversions with 2x quat multiplications. (Yes that will probably be compacted into a short form Euler to quat conversion, but the same problems apply).